# Is it posible to use the "servicefabric:/_CpuCores" load metric from ResourceMonitorService in Service Fabric to balance the services in the cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We are using "servicefabric:/_CpuCores" load metric from ResourceMonitorService in Service Fabric to auto scale services but is it also possible to use this data to balance the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric Resource Manager auto balance the cluster reacting to load changes when new services or nodes are added to the cluster.

Whenever you service scales up or down, service fabric will evaluate the cluster balance to find the right balance to avoid overloading some nodes with more services. If it finds that the cluster is unbalanced, it will move services around to accommodate the load evenly.

There are some configurations you can set to in the cluster PlacementAndLoadBalancing section to adjust the rules, you shouldn't have to change it, but in case you need, you can, please take a look in this docs [Balancing your service fabric cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-balancing).

Regarding the metrics you've set, this applies just for the service auto scaling, but whenever the service load increase, it might also trigger the cluster balance because the metrics for a node is based on all services running on it, and it will impact the node load.

You can also, use [Resource Governance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-resource-governance) to reserve node capacity to a service package, this way, SF will only place your service in a node if the node has capacity to host it, and will also prevent new services coming in if all the node capacity is reserved.